# Tracing Application Server in Use

Tags: application-server

I have a farm with 2 application servers and 2 WFE.

I need to shutdown one application server and show evidence that SharePoint is still running with only one server. How can I trace a page request to the Application Server? I was able to do it with the WFE, but not the application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show actual *usage* of the Application Server, stream the ULS logs. This will show timer jobs, web service queries, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

User page requested always go to WFE and that is why you can't trace it back to Application Server.

Application server host Central Admin and other service applications. So I would say its safe for you to shut down one of the application server. Make sure the other app server runs the timer services.

Comment: I already shut down one of the application server. I just need evidence is being used now, Do you see any way this is possible?

Comment: You mean you want to illustrate the relevance of the application server you turned off? Go to central admin -> Servers -> and find the services that runs on the app server you shut down.

Comment: I mean I want to prove that we are using the second application server and not the first. I know that the first one being TURNED OFF is pretty clear to everybody, but it was pointless to explain this to managers.

Comment: Just show them the services that runs on the second application server.. that is the only way for you to prove. And possibly explain what each service do.. https://blog.blksthl.com/2012/07/24/service-applications-in-sharepoint-2013/